# How to correctly implement the selection of an account in the picklist so that it is correctly recorded in the new contact?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist, create-records

I have a form to add a new contact and am having trouble recording if I fill in the "Account" field. If you do not fill it in, then the new contact is added to the database without any problems. What am I doing wrong? I'm just starting to learn Salesforce. It is possible that this problem has a primitive solution. Here is my code:

**//cmp**

```
    <aura:attribute name="accounts" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact',
                                                              'First Name': '',
                                                               'Last Name': '',
                                                                   'Email': '',
                                                        'Contact_Level__с': '',
                                                            'Account.Name': ''}"/>
    
    <form class="slds-form--stacked">
                        
                        ...
                        
                        <lightning:combobox aura:id="contact"
                                            label="Account"
                                            placeholder="Select account"
                                            value="{!v.contact.Account.Name}"
                                            options="{!v.accounts}"  
                                            onchange="{!c.selectAccount}"/>
                    
                        ...

                        <lightning:button label="Create" class="slds-button slds-button_brand slds-m-top--medium" onclick="{!c.saveContact}"/>
</form>
```

**//controller js**

```
getAccounts : function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.getListAccountsNew");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.accounts", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            console.log('Problem saving accounts, response state: ' + state);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Unknown problem, response state: ' + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
selectAccount: function (component, event) {
    var accountValue = event.getParam("value");
},
saveContact : function(component, event) {
    var newContact = component.get("v.contact");
    var action = component.get("c.createContact");
    action.setParams({
        "contact":newContact
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        component.find("Id_spinner").set("v.class" , 'slds-hide');
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.contactId", response.getReturnValue().Id);
            component.set("v.contact", response.getReturnValue());
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            console.log('Problem saving contact, response state: ' + state);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Unknown problem, response state: ' + state);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

**// controller apxc**

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)        
    public static List<Map<String, String>> getListAccountsNew(){
        List<Account> AccountList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Account];
        List<Map<String, String>> options = new List<Map<String, String>>();
        Integer I = 0;
        for (Account ac : AccountList) {
            options.add(new Map<String, String>());
            options.get(I).put('label',ac.Name);
            options.get(I).put('value',ac.Id);
            I = I + 1;
        }
        return options;
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Contact createContact(Contact contact){
        upsert contact;
        return contact;
    }
```

Comment: Change `value="{!v.contact.Account.Name}"` to `value="{!v.contact.AccountId}"` in the `lightning:combobox`.

Comment: Thank! You helped me a lot, it works!